# How do I fix an answer that may only be partially correct?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I had an answer to [my own question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513409/what-is-a-component-in-angularjs) that I found after doing more research on the topic.  My original intent was not to self-answer, but to add more explanation to the question that I felt was helpful  I was getting up votes on both the question and answer, but then got several down votes on the answer with no explanations as to the problem?

I obviously don't want to post wrong answers, even when I get some points as it is against the purpose of why I'm on Stack Overflow, to help others and myself, so I deleted the answer.  However, there were never any comments so I'm at a loss as to what part of the answer is wrong?   How do I go about it fixing it or do I just leave it deleted?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you actually did.  If you wanted to "add more explanation to the question" then you should have updated the question itself with the information you wanted to add.  The downvotes could reflect "Not an Answer".

Comment: Well then I didn't frame the question and the answer clearly as it helped me once I found out components were introduced in version 1.5 and I had a dev show me the "component" like structures you can get in version 1.4.  He compared the two with similar code showing me one for each version.  I honestly did not post all of this to spark debate.

Comment: @JamesDrinkard By the way, thank you for asking a reasonable and well-intentioned question on Meta about it. It's refreshing to see those amidst all of the soap box complaints that some users post regarding their own posts not faring well.

Comment: Well, my momma raised me right! :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Downvotes *generally* mean there's a problem with the answer. But it isn't always the case; it could be for any number of reasons. It could be because: 1) someone doesn't like your self-answered question (even though it's perfectly a valid thing to do on SO) 2) maybe, it's "correct" but not quite efficient, 3) perhaps, someone had a bad day and taking it out on you, 4) possibly random drive-by downvotes, 5) something is actually wrong with your answer, and so on. We'll never know the exact reason (unless downvoters explain themselves e.g., via comments).

There's no way to force downvoters to explain it - there's a reason it's anonymous and it's better if it stays that way IMO even if it's frustrating at times, as in your case here.

Sometimes, commenting "reason for downvote?" helps understand the problem in answers because *others* (not the downvoters) step in and explain why it could have been downvoted. But this isn't always guaranteed to work/help - just something I have seen work in a positive way at times.

Under the circumstances, if you don't mind occasional downvote, you can leave it undeleted considering you couldn't find any problem with it yourself. Maybe, *someone else* (a future reader) will point out the problems in your answer, if any or help it improve. That's your best bet.

Comment: Rather than "reason for downvote?" I'd suggest something that sounds more like you definitely want to improve- Something like _"I noticed that I'm getting downvotes. If someone could chime in with what I can fix on this answer, please do!"_ or similar. Just something that tries to convey that you won't be one of the bunch that ask for reasons just to argue and berate the commenter...

Comment: Agreed, that would certainly be a better way of conveying the aim of such a comment (that one wants to improve the answer).

Comment: Yes, if the intent is to help and it is, I shouldn't be influenced by some downvotes, but only if I alert everyone with a helpful comment.  I'll undelete it and add in a comment.  Thanks for the sage advice!

Comment: This is what I ended up with: "I noticed that I'm getting downvotes on this answer. If someone could explain to me to what part is wrong, please do so and I will fix it. I'm still keeping it open as I believe parts of it are correct.".  I think I got 4 downvotes and have 1 vote left, so I have to conclude something is wrong, but something had to be right as well.

Comment: 6) Shog9 lost his keys :-)

Answer (score 6):

For the particular question: the question ends up asking about a very specific concept, "Angular components" (even if you unlikely intended it), but your answer goes into some discussion about the generic meaning of "component". Every new visitor that looks for an answer will see your answer as just random discussion unrelated to the topic.

I would simply delete the answer and possibly make the question to match the current meaning of "what is an Angular component". Even if reputation is the only concern, such a move likely brings more reputation in question upvotes than improving the answer to essentially be a duplicate of the one you've accepted...

I don't think you could have predicted such a change when you've asked the question about v1.4.x, but you could have acted earlier when you got the currently accepted explanation which became the new reality with version 1.5.x.

Comment: The issue was I wasn't giving context to the versions in the answer.  Reputation wasn't really the concern, putting out a wrong answer, even if partially wrong was. I still remember when I had a problem with some SED code and had to get it fixed, even though I'd never worked with it.  After two days I was still stuck and Stack Overflow bailed me out.  So I try to give back when I can.  Nobody knows everything!